# IntelliJ/Kotlin: What does the `^use` hint mean?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I'm using Kotlin in IntelliJ. I've written a fairly typical recursive function with a couple streams to zip up some files. I'm seeing a `^use` and I don't know what IntelliJ is trying to tell me. (Hovering over such things usually teaches me something I didn't know about the language or warns me about a common mistake, but this provides no details)

Here is the screenshot of my function with an arrow pointing to the the hint.

[image: The hint <code>^use</code> in front of a call to the file input stream copyTo extension function]

Comment: it means you're implicitly returning the value of copyTo as result of of the function you're passing to `use`

Comment: Indicates the result returned by this `use` block function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This hint marks an expression that is a return value of a lambda, also saying which function the lambda is passed to. It reads as 'returned from the lambda passed to `use { ... }`'.

As the [last expression in each lambda is the return value](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#returning-a-value-from-a-lambda-expression), this hint helps finding which lambda the expression is actually returned from.

You can disable these hints in the IDE preferences: *Editor* → *General* → *Appearance* → *Show parameter hints – Configure* → *Language: Kotlin* → *Show lambda return expression hints* (also available from the hint's right click menu), the other kinds of inline hints are also set up there.

**UPD:** In IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3 and newer, these options are placed under *Editor* → *Inlay Hints* → *Kotlin*.

Comment: Definitely wouldn't have figured that out. Thanks for the detailed info and the link to the Kotlin documentation as well!

Comment: I cannot find your instructions in the settings screen, in the latest version (2019.3.2) Do you know where they moved it?

Comment: @Tobia It's under *Editor* → *Inlay Hints* → *Kotlin*. I'll update the answer.

Comment: It does not seem to work here. I had already disabled all inlay hints in that settings page, but the `^lambdaName` one still keeps being shown. It does not seem to be an "inlay hint," but something else.